# How to combine backbone with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js

I ' m trying to create an application  with the help of backbone and angular. At the moment my aim is to write some data into json and then transfer this data to the angular view. How can it be realized?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895758/using-backbone-models-with-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand Angular's intentions.

Here's a quote on the front page of backbonejs's website:

Backbone.js gives structure to web applications by providing models with key-value binding and custom events, collections with a rich API of enumerable functions, views with declarative event handling, and connects it all to your existing API over a RESTful JSON interface.

Does Angular do these things?

- binding and custom events: yes ([$scope and directives in angular](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/views-and-directives.html))
- collections with a rich API of enumberable functions: yes [(angular documentation, check out the left side)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api?PHPSESSID=cae8e98e7ca559b4605d75c813b358ee)
- views with declarative event handling: yes (controllers and $scope)
- connects it all to your existing API over a RESTful JSON interface: yes ([services, factories, & controllers in angular](http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/))